# Adding a new field to the address field type in gravity forms

Tags: plugins, php, functions, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm following the documentation for adding new address types in Gravity Forms located here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_address_types/

My goal is to add a new dropdown for County where State should be and move State and Zip to the next line together.

This documentation seems to just show how to rename the fields which are already on the address type. Is there a way to:

1. Add a new field to the address? I want to add a field County.
2. Adjust the layout of the form fields? I want the new County field above State and Zip.

Comment: Hi, 3rd party plugins, such as Gravity Forms, are considered off-topic here on WPSE. It is recommended to contact the plugin author should you have any questions regarding configuration and customization of the plugin.

Comment: The unnecessarily decreases the helpfulness of this site and restricts people to using smaller communities that are dispersed and often ghost towns for each plugin. Imagine keeping track of 30 different websites for each plugin on your to get help. Since WordPress relies on the plugin community, this help forum should allow users to leverage the community for these plugins. When WordPress creates a system that is standalone and doesn't have plugins you can restrict the topics.

Comment: There's far fewer WordPerss specific questions and that decision was made arbitrarily by the few instead of the whole.